# good cheat sheat or ref card for Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm just starting out with Rails and ActiveRecord.  I feel that anything I want to make an association between two models (`belongs_to`, `has_one`, `has_many`) I have to read the documentation over and over to really understand it.

Does anyone know of a good cheatsheet or refcard that makes the distinctions visible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you this [Guide](http://guides.rails.info/association_basics.html) (Chapter 2)

Answer (score 1):

Amy Hoy has pretty nice [ActiveRecord Relationships](http://slash7.com/cheats/activerecord_cheatsheet.pdf) cheat sheet for basics of those.

Answer (score -1):

I really like the cheat sheets on [err-the-blog](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/b)

So you could print out the [has_many](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/has_many/), [belongs_to](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/belongs_to/), and [has_one](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/has_one/) sheet and refer to them. (or bookmark them)